# How to customize navbar in Shiny R?

Tags: r, shiny, navbar

Is there a way to use a pre-made theme such as "cosmos" from the shinythemes package but to just change a few things with the navbar?

I would like to change the background color, text color, and the hover color of the navbar.

I have successfully changed the background color but am unable to find a way to change the text and color of the navbar when the mouse hovers over a tab.

This is what I have so far:

```
theme = shinytheme("cosmo"), #app theme
tags$head(tags$style(".navbar {background-color:darkgreen;}")) #navbar color
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own .css file and put it in your www directory ([see here](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/appearance.html) in the CSS section, or [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html) section 1) - *make sure the permissions are correct*.

So if you just want to slightly alter the cosmo theme then you can [download](https://bootswatch.com/cosmo/bootstrap.css) it and tweak as desired. Or create one from scratch, as in the first link, and take inspiration from cosmo (or use those commands and just add them to your UI - no need for CSS).